Import and Export not working in Typescript with package.json file
I am beginner in typescript and currently learning it. I came across a problem in importing and exporting a custom function (that i made). So basically, what i did is i made index.ts file and write this code:
export function sayHi(): void {
    console.log("Hiiii!");
}

and then i made another file (file2.ts) and wrote this code:
import  {sayHi}  from './index.js';
sayHi();

Now, this code is working perfectly fine... (without tsconfig and package.json files).
Then, I had to install inquirer so i created tsconfig file using this command:
tsc init

after creating my tsconfig file in the directory, the code is still working perfectly fine...
MY tsconfig file:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",                                 
    "module": "NodeNext",                                              
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",                     
    "esModuleInterop": true,                                                     
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,           
    "strict": true,                                            
    "skipLibCheck": true                                
  }
}

but when i created my package.json file using:
npm init --yes

then, its giving me error:
D:\Courses\GI-AIWMD\Programming\Practice2>node file2.js
file:///D:/Courses/GI-AIWMD/Programming/Practice2/file2.js:2
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
^
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'D:\Courses\GI-AIWMD\Programming\Practice2\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
at file:///D:/Courses/GI-AIWMD/Programming/Practice2/file2.js:2:23
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)
Node.js v20.10.0
My package.json file:
{
  "name": "practice2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type":"module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Note: i tried setting type: commonjs, its working fine then code is running but i cannot use inquirer package then, so i cannot set type to commonjs, it should remain type: module...

Ok so, someone told me that i was transpiling files with command: tsc index.ts file2.ts, so it was giving me error.. when i transpiled with tsc (only), then its running properly.

Follow the below steps:

npm init -y [ initialize a node project. It will create a package.json file].
npm install typescript --save-dev
tsc -init [ to initialise a typescript config file. It will create tsconfig.json file]
in tsconfig.json file set “rootDir”:’./src’ and “outDir”:’./dist’ [it is a convention]
make a folder src in project root directory and create a file index.ts inside src folder
make a folder dst in project root directory
add inside tsconfig.json "include": ["src"] which files to compile
add a script in package.json file "build": "tsc", and run npm run build in terminal.
call sayHi function from index.ts and define function in another file.

for module import install npm install @types/node --save-dev

Error in step 7.... Error: Unknown compiler option 'include'.ts
Also, I dont want to make many folders for my files, i just want to put my files directly inside the folder... i dont understand why my program is giving error with package json file while working fine without this file.

anyone???? please help me, i am still stuck...

Ok so, someone told me that i was transpiling files with command: tsc index.ts file2.ts, so it was giving me error.. when i transpiled with tsc (only), then its running properly.
